# How to add lua5.1 to CMakeLists.txt? error: lua.hpp is not found

Tags: c++, lua, cmake

I added the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED) 

include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(cmqhd ${LUA_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${GOBJECT_LIBRARIES} -lntl -lm -lgmp )
```

and I still get an error:

```
In file included from /home/kirill/Dropbox/work/dev/cmqhd/source/main.cc:10:0:
/home/kirill/Dropbox/work/dev/cmqhd/source/lua_read.h:9:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmqhd.dir/source/main.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmqhd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

the file lua_read.h has the following header:

```
#ifndef LUA_READ_H

#define LUA_READ_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <lua.hpp>
...
```

**update (1)**

```
g++ main.C -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -llua5.1
```

compiles

Comment: Does `LUA_INCLUDE_DIRS` actually contain anything?

Comment: @NicolBolas not sure how to check, the name occurred in the find file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR}` instead of `${LUA_INCLUDE_DIRS}` (dir, not dirS)